# Angular unable to find module when referencing script as ES6 module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, traceur

I have a simple plunk [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ia78MRK0UF5lGULJ7sGJ?p=info). All I am trying to do is reference the `app.js` file as an ES6 module by setting the `type` attribute of the script tag to `module`. If I add the type then Angular does not seem to find the module. If I take it out it finds it. What am I doing wrong?

The reason I want my `app.js` file to be treated as an ES6 file is so that i can import other ES6 modules so I can create my controllers and services.

I am using `traceur` for transpiling to ES5.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out with the help of the guys at Traceur:

```
<script>
      System.import("app").then(function(a){
        angular.element(document).ready(function() {
          angular.bootstrap(document, ['plunker']);
        });
      });
    </script>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/dzc0iPGAs6khvJOe0Ema?p=info

Blogged what I found over here:
http://collectivegarbage.wordpress.com/2014/10/17/angularjs-and-es6/